# Use OpenSSL for an open source project

Tags: python, openssl

I have an open-source project which can send packets using TLS/SSL. I am using OpenSSL to handle the TLS stuff. My main project uses .crt and .pem files as the certificates for sending and recieving these packets, but, as this is open-source, I don't want people to have to self-sign a certificate to develop the project. Of course, when I run the project, it gives me `OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', '', ''), ('BIO routines', '', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', '', 'system lib')]`, which is to be expected. I just want some tips or suggestions on how I could possibly make it easier to streamline this setup without removing the code for sending encrypted packets. Both the server and the client are run locally on the developers machine. I'm not amazing with TLS stuff, which is why I'm slightly confused.

All in all, I don't want people to have to self-sign a certificate in order to start running the server.

Comment: It's easy to create a self-signed certificate.  Heck, you could offer to create one for them if one doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand that, but if you share certificates, does that not make them insecure/obsolete?

Comment: I suggested creating one, not sharing one, but you're not using the cert for identification, right?  You're just using it to establish a secure connection.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I just am not *super* familiar with certificates, so I don't really know how to go about doing that.